# AWS CLI 2 can't update-service use CLI

Tags: amazon-ecs

I have a cluster on ecs everything works well! When I used aws cli v.1,  I could update my service used a command like this ***`aws ecs update-service --cluster [cluster-name] --service [service-name] --task-definition [task-name] --force-new-deployment`***. After updating CLI to v.2 I try to use this command and everything just stuck! I didn't find any changes in aws documentation. Do you have any ideas?

update:
[my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxYHK.png)
the problem is that everything starts well, without errors or warnings, it just gets stuck!

Comment: Please try the --debug option.

Comment: I tried, all the same, but with a lot of logs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The AWS CLI version 2 uses a [client-side pager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html#cli-usage-pagination-clientside). As stated in the documentation, you can "use the `--no-cli-pager` command line option to disable the pager for a single command use" (or use any of the other options described there).

Answer (score 0):

It worked. What you are seeing is the [output as documented](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecs/update-service.html#output). You can scroll through the output using up and down arrow keys or hit the `Q` key to dismiss the output.

Alternately, you can redirect the output to a file for review later:

```
aws ecs update-service ... > result.json
```

Or just ignore the output entirely:

```
aws ecs update-service ... > /dev/null
```