# AWS ECS create service waits for user input while showing output on console

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecs, circleci

I am using circleci job to create an ECS service. Below is the aws cli command that I'm using to create ECS service.

```
      aws ecs create-service --cluster "test-cluster" --service-name testServiceName \
        --task-definition testdef:1 \
        --desired-count 1 --launch-type EC2
```

When this command is executing following error is occurred and the CircleCI job is failed.

```
{ress RETURN)
"service": {
    "serviceArn": "arn:aws:ecs:*********:<account-id>:service/testServiceName",
    "serviceName": "testServiceName",
    "clusterArn": "arn:aws:ecs:*********:<account-id>:cluster/test-cluster",
    "loadBalancers": [],
    "serviceRegistries": [],
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "desiredCount": 1,
    "runningCount": 0,
    "pendingCount": 0,
    "launchType": "EC2",
    "taskDefinition": "arn:aws:ecs:*********:<account-id>:task-definition/testdef*********:1",
    "deploymentConfiguration": {
        "maximumPercent": 200,
        "minimumHealthyPercent": 100
    },
    "deployments": [
        {
            "id": "ecs-svc/1585305191116328179",
            "status": "PRIMARY",
            :

     Too long with no output (exceeded 10m0s): context deadline exceeded
```

Running the command locally on a **minimized terminal window** gives the following output

```
{
"service": {
    "serviceArn": "arn:aws:ecs:<region>:<account-id>:service/testServiceName",
    "serviceName": "testServiceName",
    "clusterArn": "arn:aws:ecs:<region>:<account-id>:cluster/test-cluster",
    "loadBalancers": [],
    "serviceRegistries": [],
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "desiredCount": 1,
    "runningCount": 0,
    "pendingCount": 0,
    "launchType": "EC2",
    "taskDefinition": "arn:aws:ecs:<region>:<account-id>:task-definition/testdef:1",
    "deploymentConfiguration": {
        "maximumPercent": 200,
        "minimumHealthyPercent": 100
    },
    "deployments": [
        {
            "id": "ecs-svc/8313453507891259676",
            "status": "PRIMARY",
            "taskDefinition": "arn:aws:ecs:<region>:<account-id>:task-definition/testdef:1",
            "desiredCount": 1,
:
```

**The further execution is stopped** until I hit some key. This is the reason that CircleCI job is failing after **10m threshold limit**. When I run the command in a **full screen terminal** locally then it does not wait and shows the output.

Is there any way that the command is run in such a way that it does not wait for any key to be hit and execution is completed so that the pipeline does not fail. Please note that the ECS service is created successfully.

Comment: Same case as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61541839/aws-cli-2-cant-update-service-use-cli